# How to detect which option is clicked in right click menu?

Tags: right-click

is there any way to detect which option has been clicked in right click menu?
can you please help us out with java/c code? 
any command prompt option to detect is also ok..
(Suse linux)

we have already tried to access system clipboard (windows) but have failed to detect

thanks..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please try to provide a little more information. What is the context of this, what code did you already try and where did you get stuck?